# Pyglet window distorted

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I'm new to pyglet, and I was following the quickstart tutorial from https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/quickstart.html

This is my main.py file:

```py
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600)

label = pyglet.text.Label("Hello World!",
                          font_name="Times New Roman",
                          color=(255, 255, 255, 255),
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x="center", anchor_y="center")


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()


pyglet.app.run()
```

This is my output:
[image]

I'm not sure if this is the expected result, may someone please explain what may be wrong here?
(Corruption, logical error, etc.)

I am using a Windows 10 OS to host the project on PyCharm v2021.1

Pyglet 1.5.15 is the only installed package, along with scipy.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The issue is related to your system but not the code. Actually the same question was asked before [Not getting clear output when using Pyglet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67009482/not-getting-clear-output-when-using-pyglet)

Comment: May someone explain to me what the system issue is?

Comment: No. How should I, without knowing your system. Actually, this is the wrong place for this question, because it is not a question about coding.

Comment: ...Where can I go for an answer to this question?

Comment: I don't know. I mean the chance of getting a proper answer her is low. Without the exact specification of your system (OS, IDE, Python and Pyglet version,...) the chance is 0.

Comment: Well I am using a editing a Python 3.8.0 file with Pycharm on a Windows 10. The version of pyglet is 1.5.15, the newest at the time of writing. My display adapter is an Intel UHD Graphics 620.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231010/discussion-between-stick-figure-and-rabbid76).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your graphics card drivers either aren't supported, aren't installed, or corrupted.

Run `pyglet -m pyglet.info`

Check and make sure it looks similar to this:

```
gl_info.get_version(): 4.6.0 - Build 27.20.100.8476
gl_info.get_vendor(): Intel
gl_info.get_renderer(): Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
```

If the version says 1.0 or 1.1, or the vendor is Microsoft then it's not installed properly.